# Virtual camera with ability to overlay notes (free software)

Tags: gratis, streaming

Virtual camera that represents stream based on real camera or desktop (full or part of) with overlay with custom marks such as text and arrows.

**EDIT:** strangely that i got downvotes and a close vote. See proprietary [Magic Camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Camera) (for Windows) for example if it's unclear what am I asking.

**EDIT2:** Ok, I'll try to rephrase: I want to place text over my camera video stream or over stream from part of desktop (what I am seeing on my screen). Better if I would be able to place not only text but arrows. Even better if this software would support picture-in-picture.

Comment: You need to add more details highlighting exactly what you need - what is a must-have? What would be nice to have?

Comment: @Undo what is unclear? I want a software that creates virtual camera device (so other programs would see it just as if another camera was connected) that would stream video of the real camera with custom positioned text (or arrows) atop of it

Comment: That there comment is much clearer than your post - I'd suggest basically combining that with the question and editing it a bit to enhance clarity and then it'll be an okay question.

Comment: @user3075942, you can use the edit capabilities to rewrite the question and make it more suitable. Use what you said in the previous comment to Undo. If you gasp in the other questions here, most people use bullet lists to show what features they need. Some information on what your intentions with the software are (what do you need it for) will be a plus. If I may advice you, comments upon downvotes and substantial improvements not regarding concrete request in the comments do not look good. Try to paraprhase the entire post if possible

Comment: After it now got a lot clearer what you're after (at least it seems like: it's kind of an "Augmented Reality" app if I got that right): For what system you are needing it? Android? iPhone? Something else?

Comment: @Izzy Why augmented reality? Just text overlay over the video! As for platform, I'm interested in a desktop app for any OS.

Comment: That's what it's called: you've got the "reality" (original camera image), and "augment" it with additional information in overlays. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality), and especially check the picture examples there. // Oh, and make sure to check the [Applications section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality#Applications) :)

Comment: Hi, this question does not meet our quality requirements and I have voted to close it. For information on how you can improve your post, please see [this post on our meta site](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out **[ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/)**, which might serve to be the right *virtual webcam utility* for you. Though there is a Pro version available, the free version of ManyCam would serve your purpose in my opinion.

Features:

- Lets more than one application to access the camera feed together at the same time.
- Add static or dynamic effects to your webcam feed.
- Overlay texts or draw objects over the video.
- Choose video files or images to be used as the webcam source.
- Setup playlists of videos to be sent as the webcam feed to applications.
- Picture-in-Picture mode which allows one video to be embedded within another.

**WARNING:** [3 out of 50 anti-virus engines](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/f2307deaf8823c8bf734ee0a93b4ba345604b184994da297a4918f7b76201396/analysis/1391798679/) in VirusTotal are showing a RED alert for the ManyCam installation file. This could possibly be due to the Toolbar which now comes bundled with the application.

But, you can (and, should) choose to **not install this toolbar** by clicking on **Cancel** when the ***Install the MyStart Toolbar*** window appears (just unchecking the two boxes wouldn't do any good). This way, there might not be any harm to your computer.

Otherwise, the program is reportedly **safe** and the first versions of the application have been pure, without even the problem of the toolbar. If you are too worried (you needn't be, in my opinion), you can just Google for an old version of the application without this toolbar.

Comment: Though there is no "draw arrow", there is general "brush" so any shapes can be drawn. And there is picture-in-picture. Thanks. Also I would like to note that the watermark [is not obligatory and can be disabled](http://blog.manycam.com/removing-the-manycam-logo/) in free version for Windows.

Comment: Hope it would serve your purpose! And, can you just confirm that there is no problem related to the toolbar?

Comment: Yes, I just pressed "Decline" to toolbar and "optimizer" and it looks like they weren't installed.

Answer (score 2):

On my old pc, I had this free application preinstalled: [WebCamEffects](http://webcameffects.net/)

I don't have it now but as I can remember you will find it usefull. You have the option to record or livestream with your webcamera and from your desktop directly. You can add effects (statics and dynamics). You can add texts also. I am not 100% sure if you can add arrows. And I don't have it now to test it, but I can remember something about custom objects. So, maybe you can include your own arrows to add on the camera.

Comment: Minor annoyance: if this software is not running at a time when other software tries to use virtual camera, then the other software crashes. As for arrows, yes, it has no direct support to draw them and I had troubles to add custom image objects (It says "No object name" even if this field isn't empty). Though thanks anyway, it's really good with text support - adjustable transparency of font and text background.

Comment: @user3075942 You are welcome. Hope it could helped you more.